# chromium-browser "--host-rules" option doesn't work?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, chromium

Good Afternoon!

Trying to use `--host-rules` option with Ubuntu/Selenium(3.8.1)+ChromeDriver(2.34.522913)+Chromium(63.0.3239.84)+Python(3.5). And it doesn't work properly.

This is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--host-rules "MAP * localhost"')
service_log_path = "~/tmp/chromedriver.log"
service_args = ['--verbose']
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver', chrome_options=chrome_options, service_args=service_args, service_log_path=service_log_path)
driver.get('http://google.com')
```

And it loads the html page. But I've mapped all hosts to localhost! (there's no proxy on localhost)

In log everything is ok:

> [1,002][INFO]: Launching chrome: /usr/bin/chromium-browser --disable-background-networking --disable-client-side-phishing-detection --disable-default-apps --disable-hang-monitor --disable-popup-blocking --disable-prompt-on-repost --disable-sync --disable-web-resources --enable-automation --enable-logging --force-fieldtrials=SiteIsolationExtensions/Control --host-rules "MAP * localhost" --ignore-certificate-errors --load-extension=/tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.nrmJ0s/internal --log-level=0 --metrics-recording-only --no-first-run --password-store=basic --remote-debugging-port=12837 --test-type=webdriver --use-mock-keychain --user-data-dir=/tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.v4TEyv data:,

Any ideas how to make it work?

Answer (score 3):

Answering my own question. Right code:

```
chrome_options.add_argument('--host-rules=MAP * localhost')
```

Without quotes around map rule.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
chrome_options.add_argument('--host-rules="MAP * localhost"')
```

Comment: Yes, i've already tried this: 

> [4810:4853:1214/175233.157213:ERROR:host_mapping_rules.cc(107)] Failed parsing rule: "MAP * localhost"

Comment: Did you include the '=' character between --host-rules and "MAP.."? It is missing in your question.

Comment: Yes:
`chrome_options.add_argument('--host-rules="MAP * localhost"')`

On my Windows station if I exec chrome.exe --host-rules="MAP * localhost" - everithing works as expected. But not on Linux in selenium+chromedriver :(

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--host-rules="MAP * localhost"')
service_log_path = "/Users/.../.../chromedriver.log" # <= bug is here check your path
service_args = ['--verbose']
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/.../.../chromedriver', chrome_options=chrome_options, service_args=service_args, service_log_path=service_log_path)
driver.get('http://google.com')
```

Comment: Tried with another quotes and "=", and the same:
`[14123:14171:1214/181915.384413:ERROR:host_mapping_rules.cc(107)] Failed parsing rule: 'MAP * localhost'`
in chromedriver.log

Comment: Works with: MacOS+Python 2.7.14/3.4.1+ChromeDriver Output: some json in log file